# PostgreSQL - Extract string before ending delimiter

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column of data that looks like this:

```
58,0:102,56.00
52,0:58,68
58,110
57,440.00
52,0:58,0:106,6105.95
```

I need to extract the character before the last delimiter (',').

Using the data above, I want to get:

```
102
58
58
57
106
```

Comment: `I need to extract the character ..` Your desired result lists numbers, not characters. Please clarify. Define what you consider separating characters besides the mentioned ','.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be done with a regular expression in [`substring()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL). If you want:
***the longest string of only digits before the last comma***:

```
substring(data, '(\d+)\,[^,]*$')
```

Or you may want:
***the string before the last comma  (',') that's delimited at the start either by a colon (':') or the start of the string.***
Could be another regexp:

```
substring(data, '([^:]*)\,[^,]*$')
```

Or this:

```
reverse(split_part(split_part(reverse(data), ',', 2), ':', 1))
```

More verbose but typically much faster than a (expensive) regular expression.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d7c10d8922f5f0c405d83717e0f81ae9)*

Answer (score 0):

Can't promise this is the best way to do it, but it is a way to do it:

```
with splits as (
  select string_to_array(bar, ',') as bar_array
  from foo
),
second_to_last as (
  select
    bar_array[cardinality(bar_array)-1] as field
  from splits
)
select
  field,
  case
    when field like '%:%' then split_part (field, ':', 2)
    else field
  end as last_item
from second_to_last
```

I went a little overkill on the CTEs, but that was to expose the logic a little better.

Answer (score 0):

With a CTE that removes everything after the last comma and then splits the rest into an array:

```
with cte as (
  select
    regexp_split_to_array(
      replace(left(col, length(col) - position(',' in reverse(col))), ':', ','),
      ','
    ) arr                                             
  from tablename  
)  
select arr[array_upper(arr, 1)] from cte
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9nKbHcmatKF1pDgdZ3ZrTL/2).
Results:

```
| result |
| ------ |
| 102    |
| 58     |
| 58     |
| 57     |
| 106    |
```

Answer (score 0):

The following treats the source string as an "array of arrays". It seems each data element can be defined as S(x,y) and the overall string as S1:S2:...Sn.
The task then becomes to extract x from Sn.

```
with as_array as 
     ( select string_to_array(S[n], ',') Sn 
         from (select string_to_array(col,':') S
                    , length(regexp_replace(col, '[^:]','','g'))+1  n 
                 from tablename 
              ) t
     )
select Sn[array_length(Sn,1)-1] from as_array
```

The above extends S(x,y) to S(a,b,...,x,y) the task remains to extracting x from Sn. If it is the case that all original sub-strings S are formatted S(x,y) then the last select reduces to **select Sn[1]**